# Any case other than $0$ for $a=-a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I was wondering about a rather simple type of problem. This is not any sort of homework but I was working on problems in linear algebra and in any cases that we have $a=-a$ we can simplify to then $a=0$. My question is, is there any sort of field/ring etc for which $a=-a$ would not always imply that $a=0$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding $a$ to both sides gives $2a = 0$. In a field, this implies $a = 0$ if and only if $0 \neq 2$, as then we can divide both sides by $2$. A field where $0 = 2$ is said to have [characteristic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_%28algebra%29) equal to $2$.

Comment: Okay, what also motivated by question is I was asked to show that the set of Skew-Symettric matrices form a subspace ( unspecified). I showed that the 0 matrix was skew symmetric and I also showed closure under addition and scalar multiplication, however I left the diagonals as a and a' but I specified a=-a.. Would you still say this is a completely valid proof that it is a subspace and in fact may be even more general than making it 0?

Comment: That is absolutely valid. In fact it's wrong to assume that the diagonal consists of zeros, that's not true over fields of characteristic $2$ (where skew-symmetric is the same as symmetric).

Comment: Great! And lastly, would the dimension of the subspace change depending on this? For example with real field you get dim 1 but how about if it was just a=-a?

Comment: It does. The vector space of skew-symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrices over a field of characteristic $2$ has dimension $3$ instead.

Comment: Ah I see, but would leaving it in the form a=-a and such still be valid over the regular field, but still with dim 1?

Comment: Yes, because then $a = -a$ is equivalent to $a = 0$.